# What is a Jeeves Word™?

Tags: wordplay, pattern, word-property

<sub><sup>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sup></sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Jeeves Word™**.

Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Jeeves Words™ | Not Jeeves Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SIR | MADAM |
| RANG | CALLED |
| PRESS | MEDIA |
| FLOWER | FLOUR |
| LIGHT | DARK |
| PART | WHOLE |
| TAIL | HEAD |
| FIN | FLUKE |
| LIVER | PANCREAS |
| LAY | LIE |
| COMMISSION | FEE |
| NI | EKIEKIEKIEKIPATANGZOOMPOING |
| PLOY | PLOT |
| SIGN | SING |
| BRIEF | BRIE |
| FLAT | FLOAT |

This puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption that each word can be individually determined as being either a **Jeeves Word™** or a **Not Jeeves Word™**, without depending on the other words. There are more words in both categories.

Should you need it, here's a CSV version for easier copy-pasting:

```
Jeeves Words™, Not Jeeves Words™           
SIR, MADAM
RANG, CALLED
PRESS, MEDIA
FLOWER, FLOUR
LIGHT, DARK
PART, WHOLE
TAIL, HEAD
FIN, FLUKE
LIVER, PANCREAS
LAY, LIE
COMMISSION, FEE
NI, EKIEKIEKIEKIPATANGZOOMPOING 
PLOY, PLOT
SIGN, SING
BRIEF, BRIE
FLAT, FLOAT
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is EKIEKIEKIEKIPATANGZOOMPOING? :-)

Comment: @Anonymous [With pleasure!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZvsGdJP3ng)

Comment: This question is proof that there's still plenty of life and imagination to be found in this puzzle format :) Very satisfying when there's clever wordplay involved - more of this and less of setters-making-us-add-up-all-the-numeric-values-of-the-letters-in-a-bunch-of-words, please!

Comment: Agreeing with Stiv here - this is a *brilliant* puzzle. I absolutely adore it.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice however, if the Knights Who Say EKIEKIEKIEKIPATANGZOOMPOING went back to being the Knights Who Say Ni would they not be **DE**EKIEKIEKIEKIPATANGZOOMPOING**ED**?

Comment: @ElPedro I have to admit that is the single word whose non-existence I didn't triple check with a stack of dictionaries :-)

Comment: (Also, thanks for the lavish praise, guys. I'm blushing a bit here..)

Comment: Surely EKIEKIEKIEKIPATANGZOOPOING (no M) !?!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A Jeeves Word™ is one which

> forms another word when placed in DE_ED, as Jeeves would say 'Indeed, sir.'

The words are

> DESIRED
>  DERANGED
>  DEPRESSED
>  DEFLOWERED
>  DELIGHTED
>  DEPARTED
>  DETAILED
>  DEFINED
>  DELIVERED
>  DELAYED
>  DECOMMISSIONED
>  DENIED
>  DEPLOYED
>  DESIGNED
>  DEBRIEFED
>  DEFLATED

Comment: [Indeed, sir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te3SvM-aG04&t=441s).

Comment: How long did it take you to figure that out?